# sed to process an OFX, extracting payee from <MEMO> and printing on <NAME>

Tags: awk, sed, ofx

I'm processing a OFX (bank transactions) file. My bank doesn't use the `<NAME>` tag to specify the payee, but this information is a substring of `<MEMO>` tag.

So, my file is something like:

```
...ofx headers and other stuff
...line below is a transaction
<STMTTRN>
    <TRNTYPE>OTHER</TRNTYPE>
    <DTPOSTED>20160609120000</DTPOSTED>
    <TRNAMT>-4.00</TRNAMT>
    <FITID>2016060914000</FITID>
    <CHECKNUM>000000700132</CHECKNUM>
    <REFNUM>700.132</REFNUM>
    <MEMO>Credit Card Payment - 09/06 18:37 Walmart 2th street</MEMO>
</STMTTRN>
...continues other transactions and end of file
```

I would like to match every `<MEMO>` tag, extract the payee name (`Walmart 2th street` in this example) and write a new line with a `<NAME>`. My output would be like:

```
...ofx headers and other stuff
...line below is a transaction
<STMTTRN>
    <TRNTYPE>OTHER</TRNTYPE>
    <DTPOSTED>20160609120000</DTPOSTED>
    <TRNAMT>-4.00</TRNAMT>
    <FITID>2016060914000</FITID>
    <CHECKNUM>000000700132</CHECKNUM>
    <REFNUM>700.132</REFNUM>
    <MEMO>Credit Card Payment - 09/06 18:37 Walmart 2th street</MEMO>
    <NAME>Walmart 2th street</NAME>
</STMTTRN>
...continues other transactions and end of file
```

Another tool as awk can be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/.*<MEMO>.* [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} (.*)<.*/&\n    <NAME>\1<\/NAME>/' file
```

Output:

```
<STMTTRN>
    <TRNTYPE>OTHER</TRNTYPE>
    <DTPOSTED>20160609120000</DTPOSTED>
    <TRNAMT>-4.00</TRNAMT>
    <FITID>2016060914000</FITID>
    <CHECKNUM>000000700132</CHECKNUM>
    <REFNUM>700.132</REFNUM>
    <MEMO>Credit Card Payment - 09/06 18:37 Walmart 2th street</MEMO>
    <NAME>Walmart 2th street</NAME>
</STMTTRN>
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: Using -i, lines where I have a latin character the regex don't match:
<MEMO>Cartão de Crédito - 09/06 18:37 Walmart 2th street</MEMO>

Comment: I gave up on non ascii chars. I wrote an answer below to format the code.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @Cyrus answer to deal with no ascii chars:

I gave up on non ascii chars and now it's working:

```
iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" file-ansi.ofx -o file-utf8.ofx
rm file-ansi.ofx
sed 'y/áÁàÀãÃâÂéÉêÊíÍóÓõÕôÔúÚüÜçÇ/aAaAaAaAeEeEiIoOoOoOuUuUcC/' -i file-utf8.ofx
sed -i -r 's/.*<MEMO>.* [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} (.*)<.*/&\n                  <NAME>\1<\/NAME>/' file-utf8.ofx
```

My output:

```
<MEMO>Cartao de Credito - 09/06 18:37 Walmart 2th</MEMO>
<NAME>Walmart 2th street</NAME>
```

Comment: Both GNU and BSD `sed` should be able to handle UTF-8 input properly (assuming your locale is UTF-8-based), so I don't think you need the `rm` and `sed 'y/...'` commands. `sed -E 's/[[:alpha:]]/a letter/' <<<'ã'` shows that the non-ASCII letter is recognized as such.